# Hide main page content while in the Stack Snippet editor so that browser Find (Control-F) behavior is intuitive

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

In most browsers, one can press Control-F or something similar to search the current page for a phrase. Pressing Enter will usually scroll you to the next match for the found string. This is extremely useful when programming - quickly identifying the location of each reference to a variable name or key string is quite helpful when debugging.

Unfortunately, the Stack Snippet editor has some problems with this: while one can of course search while inside the editor, matches to the searched string *outside the editor* will be included (and scrolled to with Enter) as well. This might be clearer with an image. Taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231134/sticky-header-jagged-movement/55231200) as an example, the question involves (among other things) a `.header-text` element. Say I copy the snippet to an answer and start debugging by looking for the CSS rule for `header-text`. I press Control-F, type in `header-text`, and see:

[image]

Even though the code in the snippet I'm editing only has 2 matches for the string, I'm shown 14 matches from all over the page (the exact number varies) because the question and other answers contain the string I'm searching for too. I'd either have to press enter 12 times to get to the first match in the snippet editor (match #13), or shift-enter to iterate backwards, which is unintuitive. (The snippet editor matches are always at the end, eg [matches 13/14 and 14/14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMYMM.png)). Answer code which is partially copied from the code in the question is extremely typical on SO, so this issue of a browser finding undesirable matches outside the snippet interface is quite common.

A simple enough solution would be for the background to be hidden while the snippet editor is open - give everything but the `.snippet-modal` and `.lightbox` `display: none`. These hidden elements will not be "found" by the browser when searching (at least not in Chrome and FF), so this ensures that only matches inside the interface will be found/highlighted:

[image]

Any solution that allows for intuitive Find behavior inside the snippet editor would be welcome - hiding the main page content just looks like one possibility.

Answer (score 5):

Short of an official fix, one way for ordinary users to fix this themselves would be to install a userscript that appends the `<style>` tag (as in the final image in the question) when the snippet editor is opened, and then removes it when the editor is closed. You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/). Technical details are in comments in the script body.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Stack Snippet Find
// @author           CertainPerformance
// @description      Makes control-f inside snippet editor only show results inside the editor
// @description      https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381900/hide-main-page-content-while-in-the-stack-snippet-editor-so-that-browser-find-c/381901
// @version          1.01
// @include          /https://stackoverflow.com/questions\/\d/
// @include          /https://stackoverflow.com/posts/\d+/edit/
// @include          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

const style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = `
body > *:not(.snippet-modal):not(.lightbox) {
  display: none;
}
`;

// This runs when the user has either clicked on "Edit the above snippet",
// or on the create-snippet icon at the top of the textarea:
const listenForSnippetClose = (textarea) => {
  document.body.appendChild(style);
  const origScrollY = window.scrollY;
  // Listen for when the .snippet-modal is removed from the DOM
  // so that the style added above can be removed at the same time:
  const mutCallback = (mutations) => {
    const snippetModalRemoved = Array.prototype.some.call(
      mutations,
      ({ removedNodes }) => removedNodes[0] && removedNodes[0].matches('.snippet-modal')
    );
    if (snippetModalRemoved) {
      style.remove();
      window.scrollTo(0, origScrollY);
      textarea.focus();
      // the text caret position set by SO's JS will be preserved,
      // no fiddling necessary even though the textarea is focused again
    }
  };
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutCallback);
  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true });
};

window.addEventListener(
  'click',
  ({ target }) => {
    if (target.className !== 'edit-snippet' && !target.matches('.wmd-snippet-button > span')) {
      return;
    }
    const textarea = target.closest('.post-editor').querySelector('textarea');
    listenForSnippetClose(textarea);
  },
  // Need to trigger listener in capturing phase
  // because "Edit the above snippet" click event will have stopPropagation called on it by SO's JS:
  true
);

// When in snippet editor, when escape key is pressed, call stopPropagation in the capturing phase
// so that the editor doesn't try to close, if you just wanted to close the browser's Find box
window.addEventListener(
  'keyup',
  (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape' && document.querySelector('.snippet-modal')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  },
  true
);

/* Code related to editor opening/closing in SO's JS can be found here:
  https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/snippet-javascript.en.js
     search for: onShow: function (editorClosed) {
  where editorClosed is
  https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/external-editor.en.js
    search for: var editorClosed = function (newImageUrl, customRenderCode) {
*/
```

This userscript also fixes the semi-related problem of an `esc` keypress being interpreted as an attempt to escape from the snippet interface, when in fact one may well have simply wanted to dismiss the browser's `find` box after searching. (Without the script, if you press `esc`, Stack Overflow's built-in JS will either remove the interface without prompting if you haven't made any changes yet, or will give you a `confirm` dialog for the same.) With this userscript, instead of pressing `esc`, press the Cancel button instead.